# How to monitor complete file transfer without using delay in java

Tags: java, file

I am receiving file from external application in a path in my system, I want to fetch this file once it is completely received. How to check whether the file is completely received? I don't want to check either by using delay or by comparing previous and current size

Comment: How are you reading in the file? If it's with a blocking call, you can easily notify yourself once this call is done, no?

Comment: I can use blocking call but I have no idea how to get notified when the file has been completely received. Kindly please help me

Comment: Please show your code. "Receiving" can mean anything. It is not clear, what your understanding of "receiving" is.

Comment: An external application(which I have not coded) is sending a file to a particular path in my system(in linux). The size of file is unknown, I want to know when exactly the receiving is completed so that I can fetch that file at that moment

Comment: How will you know if the file transfer actually completed without error and didn't produce a partial file?

Answer (score 1):

What I've seen done is when still receiving the file add an extension to filename like foo.bar.temp. Then, when receiving is done, rename to just foo.bar. Your watcher thread would then ignore anything with .temp at end (or whatever you add to end).

---

I missed the receiving from external app part. Is there any way to get some kind of notification of the file size separate from receiving the file? If you receive notification that you're about to receive a file of "N" bytes, you can keep checking size until it matches...

Comment: The file which I am receiving is large size, so I want to know when exactly the receiving is completed

Comment: @varsha what jjazz is saying downloaded file is ignored because it has different extension. Only after download completed file is renamed and you know it is downloaded. But since file is "downloaded" by external application it may not work, that depends on that application. If I remember correctly Chrome browser does rename files from some temporary extension after file is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

*Nevermind, just found your comment saying it's from an external application..*

---

Do you want to do something like implement a listener paradigm?
If so, you can try something like this:

```
public abstract class FileReceiver {
    private final List<FileRecievedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    public final void addFileReceivedListener(FileRecievedListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    /** Calls `receiveFile` and notifies all listeners when the file has been recieved */
    public final File recieveFileAndNotifyListeners() {
        File f = recieveFile();
        for (FileRecievedListener listener : listeners)
            listener.onFileRecieved(f);
        return f;
    }

    /** Receive the file however you will.. */
    protected abstract File recieveFile();

    /** Interface for anything that wants to listen for the file being received */
    public interface FileRecievedListener {
        public void onFileRecieved(File file);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileRecievedListener listener = new FileRecievedListener() {
            @Override public void onFileRecieved(File file) {
                System.out.println("I recieved the file! " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        };
        FileReceiver fr = new FileReceiver() {
            @Override public File recieveFile() {
                return new File("this/is/a/sample/file.txt");
            }
        };
        fr.addFileReceivedListener(listener);
        fr.recieveFileAndNotifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The kind of process which creates the file or sends the file is not clear to answer this question accurately; the actual scene is not known here. One can try this using a service like this:

1. The file gets created in a monitored (known) folder; one can know
   the file creation by using
   [java.nio.file.WatchService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html).
2. Once file create notification is received thru the watch service - start another service (lets call it 'file-receiving-monitor') to monitor the file receiving until completion.
3. This file-receiving-monitor checks the file size attribute every few xx millisecs or secs (of interval) until there is no more file size change between the interval. And perform this no more file size change check for few more times to make sure the receiving is over. At the point - of no more changes to the file size - it can be concluded that the file is received completely.

Note that this file-receiving-monitor can be built using a [java.util.Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) API.

Comment: Yes I had this idea but I thought it was not that efficient, now I have no other option I should go for this. Thank you

Comment: This is based on **hope**.  Checking the file size for no more growth isn't accurate - no matter what the delay is, once you decide the file is done growing, it can grow again.  And doing something like checking if the file is still open via something like `lsof` can't handle either processes that may reopen the file, nor any errors that leave a partial file.